# What are the advantages and disadvantages of using bitvectors/bit manipulation?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitvector

This question came up while I was working with bitvectors in C. From what I understand, they're good to use since they allow you to store the same data but with less memory, although I could be wrong. However, I find that the outcome when printing that data can be confusing, I don't know what the numbers being printed in the terminal represent since they've been manipulated. So why would you or would you not use bitvectors?

Comment: The answer to this question is dependent on the language. You should either add the target language or rephrase your question so it becomes language-agnostic

Comment: @Schottky Sorry for the late response, I'm referring to C and have updated the post.